# Cannot run shell scripts on OS Monterrey (12.3.1) after update from Big Sur (11.4)

Tags: command-line, script, monterey

I use shell scripts a lot. Ever since upgrading to OS Monterrey 12.3.1, none of my shell scripts will run.  They are in the same locations they were before the upgrade to Monterrey.

I execute a shell script simply by typing it's name in bash terminal from within the script's directory, and pressing enter:

```
~ cd /path/to/shellscript
~ shellscriptname [enter]
```

In Big Sur, the script would run and the files would get copied, but in Monterrey,

```
 $ copyTestFiles
 -bash: copyTestFiles: command not found
```

There are no errors - just this response.

The script is set for execution

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/python
$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is your shell and $PATH - I would expect running in the directory of the executable to fail unless you have explicitly made running in the current directory work which if you have done is not recommended

Comment: @mmmmmm - in Big Sur (11.4) all my scripts ran fine.  shell is `Bash` and $PATH `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: WHere are your scripts? Your PATH is a mess - what python do you use an what is in /root/bin, that is not a normal directory

Comment: @mmmmmm Not sure what PATH has to do with the script returning `command not found`?  Would you please explain the connection?

Comment: It means that the command you typed into the shell cannot be found. shells use $PATH to find the command/executable

Comment: @mmmmmm Path is a mess because the Monterrey update actually emptied the environmental variable PATH - I am trying to rebuild it.

Comment: You'll have to provide more info (& clarity about the info you've provided) to get any idea what's going wrong. First, is that actually the complete error message you get? Exact error messages matter (see [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough/359147#359147)), so make sure it's shown fully and accurately (and correctly formatted -- is there supposed to be a space at the beginning?). Second, how exactly are you running the scripts (i.e. with `./scriptname`, `bash scriptname`, or something else)?

Comment: As has been asked already, copy *all* the lines up to and including the error you get. I'm quite sure the error message says `-bash: shellscriptname: command not found` but this should be part of the question. Also, include `echo $PATH` and its output directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-bash: copyTestFiles: command not found` is the error as returned by `bash`, indicating that `bash` didn't find the shell script.

From `man bash` (COMMAND EXECUTION):

```
If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no
slashes, bash searches each element of the PATH for a  directory con-
taining an executable file by that name
```

So to find a shell script/command ("name" in the context of the man page excerpt) in the current directory, `PATH` must include a `.` entry for the current directory. This is bad security practice though (e.g. an attacker could add a file called `ls` in a directory), so it's better to use `./copyTestFiles` to execute a shell script in the current directory (or to add the full path to `PATH`).

Comment: ./copyTestFiles works - I can only assume `.` used to be in the path.

Comment: The only way that would have been, would be if you had put it there, and upgrading to Monterey from Big Sur would not have removed the shell rc file you'd put that change in.  So it wasn't the case before.

Comment: @MarcWilson It might have been in /etc/paths.

Comment: @MarcWilson - Monterrey upgrade cleared out my PATH environment variable.

Comment: @nohillside Installing Monterey over the top of Big Sur shouldn't have removed anything that was in /etc/paths, I would think.

Comment: @RoyHinkley Environment variables are not preserved even between different invocations of the shell, so there's nothing for the Monterey upgrade to clear out. Your environment is built (separately in each Terminal window) by various shell startup scripts; those shouldn't have been cleared out either, but it's possible your default shell switched from bash to zsh, in which case it'll be running different startup scripts now.

Comment: @MarcWilson /etc/paths gets reset AFAIK, the content of /etc/paths.d doesn‘t.

Comment: Also doesn't everything in /etc/path* need to be absolute paths?

Comment: @mmmmmm Not at all. If you add `.`, `/usr/lib/path_helper` will happily include this in the PATH variable it creates.